# chrome devtools extension: CORS issues on windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, cors, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome extension, where I add a panel in the devtools, from where I need to perform some ajax calls.

[From what I read](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr), I have to add my domain in the manifest.json permissions:

```
{
  ...
  "permissions": ["https://example.com/"]
}
```

And from within my devtools panel, I'm now able to perform api calls to the server.

Except that on chrome-windows, nothing works.

From what I could observe:

- osX, linux: as long as the domain is authorized, everything works fine
- windows: a pre-flight request is sent although the domain should be authorized. It then fails, and everything is blocked

Is there something I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, without changing anything the extension seems to behave as expected now.

My guess is that there was some bug on chrome/windows that have been fixed since. Closing the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're having trouble with regard to CORS in chrome extension, check the [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr) guide. There's a [Requesting cross-origin permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr) which details how you can implement cross-origin permissions.

There's also a handy chrome extension app called [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/reviews?hl=en) which might help when testing xhr requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, the doc was what I was referencing to. It only says we should ask the domain in the permissions, and that is exactly what I did !

Comment: I have a similar problem, my application is built using Angular 7. I am making an ajax call to a BPMS server which works fine in IE but I have a CORS error in Chrome. However when I copy the ajax url to the Chrome browser I have all the data. Can anyone help?